# Azure SQL database upgrade

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-load-balancer

Im wondering something regarding this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-application-rolling-upgrade

We would like to perform a database upgrade involving ~3 million records in a table. The upgrade will add an extr column to the mentioned table, which can take up to 5 minutes to complete.

In short, Microsoft suggest creating a transactionally consistent database copy of the target database, perform the database upgrade/migration and switch users to that copy using a load balancer.

This seems all and well, but records created in the original database will not be present in the upgraded/migrated database copy.

`Turn the primary database to read-write mode and run the upgrade script in the stage slot (5).` - is what the article suggest.

If the primary database is read-write mode, won't i be missing data in the upgraded/migrated copy of the primary database once i point everyone to the new database?

*For example: would it be possible to sync database records from the primary to the secondary once the secondary is upgraded and front-end users are pointed to the secondary database?*